# measure state update from within event handler function

Tags: reactjs

React Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/254140/

I have this code below that's supposed to validate if 2 email addresses match.

I discovered that state updates aren't recognized immediately, inside `handleChange`. That is, `handleChange` needs to be called again for the snippet `this.state.email === this.state.email2...` to catch state updates.

(I was able to solve my original issue using a different technique. I put a version of the snippet `this.state.email === this.state.email2...` directly *inside* the `<span>`).

**My question:** how would you modify the code so that the snippet `this.state.email === this.state.email2...` immediately recognizes that state has been updated? It would seem this calls for a callback function or method chaining. (I encourage more experienced devs to please edit my question for clarity).

```
class Signup extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
            email: "",
            email2: "",
            email_match_message: ""
        };
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <div>
                    email: <input type="email" name="email" value={ this.state.email } onChange={ this.handleChange } /><br />
                    email2: <input type="email" name="email2" value={ this.state.email2 } onChange={ this.handleChange } /><span>{ this.state.email_match_message }</span><br />

                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }

    handleChange = ({ target }) => {
        this.setState({
            [target.name]: target.value
        });

        this.state.email === this.state.email2 ? this.setState({email_match_message: "emails match"}): this.setState({email_match_message: "emails don't match"});
    }
}
```

Post-answer note to self, for future reference: setState is asynchronous, hence this problem was happening. I was also able to solve this by wrapping the snippet in `setTimeout` to delay its execution (Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/254200/ )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
handleChange = ({ target }) => {
    this.setState({
        [target.name]: target.value
    }, () => {
        const { email, email2 } = this.state;
        email === email2 ? this.setState({email_match_message:"emails match"}) : this.setState({email_match_message: "emails don't match"});
    });
}
```

This code would solve your issue, as it waits until setState is complete. However best case scenario you wouldn't setState twice in one function. Could be something like this:

```
handleChange = ({ target }) => {
    const oppositeEmail = target.name === "email" ? "email2" : "email";
    const changedEmail = target.value;

    const emailMatchMessage = changedEmail === this.state[oppositeEmail] ? "emails match" : "emails dont match";

    this.setState({
        [target.name]: target.value,
        email_match_message: emailMatchMessage
    });    //added a closing paren
}
```